# null values in jQuery Templates rendered incorrectly when using Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-templates

Fearing it is a bug, hoping it is just me:

I am using a jquery.tmpl template in a knockout.js data-binding. The template uses the jquery.tmpl notation to bind to properties: `${Name}`. It turns out that when the 'Name' property is `null`, the template renders a 4 letter string `"null"` into the HTML. This is awkward. (**Note:** Name is a ko.observable in this case).

If I use the template manually `$("#rowTemplate").tmpl(item).appendTo($("tbody"))` and `Name` is *not* an observable then jQuery template renders an empty string. This is much more like the behaviour I'd expect.

Drawing the whole thing one step further, if I do a null-check in the template by using:

```
{{if Name != null}}
    <input value="${Name}" />
{{/if}}
```

Then plain jQuery template does not render the input box. However, when using the template with knockout.js, the condition `Name != null` is false, because `Name` is an observable. On the other hand, `{{if Name() != null}}` is an invalid jQuery template syntax.

I did not find any way around this issue. Would anyone be able to tell me how to use jQuery templates correctly in conjunction with knockout.js? Or do I have to report a bug to the knockout project?

---

Example HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="knockout-1.3.0beta.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead><tr><th>Name</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'rowTemplate', foreach: items }"> </tbody>
    </table>

    <script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
        {{if Name != null}}
            <tr><td>${Name}</td></tr>
        {{/if}}
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var rawItems = [{ "Name": null }, { "Name": "Me"}];
        var boundData = {
            items: ko.mapping.fromJS(rawItems)
        };

        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Knockout way:
            ko.applyBindings(ko.mapping.fromJS({ items: rawItems }));

            // Non-knockout way:
            //$.each(rawItems, function () {
            //    $("#rowTemplate").tmpl(this).appendTo($("tbody"));
            //});
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing `{{if Name() != null}}` or even just `{{if Name()}}` is the right syntax in the `if`.  http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/92ssx/.

Otherwise, you can switch to `<td data-bind="text: Name"></td>` which will at least render empty string.  One additional alternative is to do `${Name() ? Name : ''}`

Comment: Hm strange. As I stated, I tried `Name() != null`, and I got an exception

Comment: Is there a certain browser?  Do you have the issue in the fiddle?

Comment: No, in your fiddle example executed in Firefox 6.0.2 it seems to work. I will have a second look at my code. I have the issue in IE9. I'll update as soon as I have tried again.

Comment: Have tried again. It works. Don't know what the problem was last time........... I'm considering to delete the question - though it may still have a minor use for future readers.

Comment: Any idea what the support range of this is? Android phones 2.x's native browsers does not handle the null properties and thus not rendering the page all together.

Comment: Although this is an old case, I've tried {{if Name()}} and got an exaction when I had a value inside the Name property " TypeError: Name.call is not a function ".So this way it worked for me - {{if Name != ""  && Name !=  null }}